# Need the SQL query to find this result

Tags: sql

This is the source table with data

```
PARENT_ID   PARENT_NAME CHILD_GENDER
------------------------------------
1111        AAA         M
1111        AAA         F
1234        BBB         M
1234        BBB         M
1235        CCC         M
1236        DDD         F
1236        DDD         F
1236        DDD         M
1237        EEE         M
1237        EEE         M
1237        EEE         F
1238        FFF         F
1239        GGG         F
1239        GGG         F
```

And I need to find out the `Parent_ID` who has children with gender both M & F.

The required output is this:

```
PARENT_ID   PARENT_NAME CHILD_GENDER
------------------------------------
1111        AAA         M
1111        AAA         F
1236        DDD         F
1236        DDD         F
1236        DDD         M
1237        EEE         M
1237        EEE         M
1237        EEE         F
```

What is the SQL query?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 2):

You can use aggregation to find out the parent_ids that have children of both gender (hence the distinct count 2) and join with your original table to get the corresponding rows.

```
select t.*
from your_table t
join (
    select parent_id
    from your_table
    group by parent_id
    having count(distinct child_gender) = 2
    ) t2 on t.parent_id = t2.parent_id;
```

Comment: Zero-attempt questions are better closed than answered.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - It could be the case or as the user, being pretty new to the site, may not know how to ask. (providing attempts etc). But I think the OP still did a pretty good job of providing sample data and expected output. Most of the new joiners post images (sometimes not even that).

Comment: Ditto GurV's comment.